# How to re-assign a variable in a function in Racket?

Tags: racket

I want to initialize acc as 0. I want to add the length of each element of lst. I understand this is not the easiest way to do it, but I simplified my real code for this example. How exactly can I accumulate the total length and assign it to acc.

Also, I am trying to avoid using set! or other ! commands.

```
(define (total-length-list lst)
  (define acc 0)
    (for/list ([i lst])
      (cond [(= 0 (length i)) (+ acc 0)]
            [(= 1 (length i)) (+ acc 1)]
            [(= 2 (length i)) (+ acc 2)]))
  acc)
```

Comment: I notice you aren't using the list produced by `for/list`. If you want to accumulate something, usually `for/fold` is better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description I would implement it with `apply` and `map`.

```
;; total-length-list : [Listof [Listof Any]] -> Natural
(define (total-length-list lst)
  (apply + (map length lst)))
```

If you want to use a loop, then `for/sum` is good.

```
;; total-length-list : [Listof [Listof Any]] -> Natural
(define (total-length-list lst)
  (for/sum ([i lst])
    (length i)))
```

If you want to use an accumulator, `for/fold` can do that.

```
;; total-length-list : [Listof [Listof Any]] -> Natural
(define (total-length-list lst)
  (for/fold ([acc 0]) ([i lst])
    (+ acc (length i))))
```

And if you still want that `cond` for some reason, you can put that inside the `for/fold`, but make sure to have an `else` case that returns the accumulator unchanged.

```
;; total-length-list : [Listof [Listof Any]] -> Natural
(define (total-length-list lst)
  (for/fold ([acc 0]) ([i lst])
    (cond [(= 0 (length i)) (+ acc 0)]
          [(= 1 (length i)) (+ acc 1)]
          [(= 2 (length i)) (+ acc 2)]
          [else             acc])))
```

If you leave out the `[else acc]` in the cond you might get an error about `#<void>`.

But simpler is better, so I would recommend either using `apply` with `map`, or using `for/sum`, no accumulators or conditionals necessary.

**From an imperative programmer's point of view**,

```
(for/fold ([acc init]) ([elem lst])
  body)
```

returns the same value as

```
(define acc init)
(for ([elem lst])
  (set! acc body))
acc
```

However, `for/fold` does it without any mutation/`set!` necessary.